# what is best/right way to call postgres function or stored procedure from nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using "pg" module to handle with postgresql db ,what how to call function using pg i have doubt,

I am calling function using query method,

```
client.query("SELECT * FROM SQSP_IsUserNameExists($1)",[userName], function(err, result) {
  // some code.

});
```

that is working fine, but is this right way to call postgresql functions.

Comment: How is the structure for your stored procedure?

Answer (score 8):

Your code looks correct.

But if you want a nicer syntax, example with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```js
// calling a function:
const result = await db.func('funcName', [userName]);
//=> SELECT * FROM funcName('user-name')

// calling a stored procedure:
const result = await db.proc('procName', [userName]);
//=> CALL procName('user-name')
```

Answer (score -1):

From the PostgrSQL side, if the function returns a result set than yes the SQL is syntax is correct. As for the Node call syntax I am not familiar with that framework. But if its returning results then I say task complete.